# Easiest way to have button open browser to specific URL

Tags: android, browser, button, onclick

It's a simple app I've got and I'd like the button I've made to launch a specific URL via the browser. Could you guys give me a little info to get this going, like I've said I've got the button already to go in my app. Here's the code -- lemme' know if you need anything else

.java File

```
package reseeveBeta.mpi.dcasey;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ReseeveBetaActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                
    }  

}
```

.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Reseeve, tap register to begin account creation" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="If you already have and account, please login below" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This line should open your built-in browser, with the specified url:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

Your Activity should have parts like this:

```
//define class variables here
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //some code of yours
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    //more code of yours
}

//whatever else you have in your source code

public void onClick(View v)
{
    //handle the click events here, in this case open www.google.com with the default browser
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
}
```

It might not be 100% accurate syntax, since I did just write this on my own, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll report back if there's any issues -- thanks again!

Comment: If it is the thing you wanted to do, and helped you, can you accept it as answer?

Comment: I wasn't able to compile/run after adding to my project. Where exactly should I put it?

Comment: If you want the browser to open after you click on your button, than you should first register your button for events, btn.setOnClickListener(this); for example, than in the onClick(arg) method, you can paste this line. Obviously, replace www.google.com with whatever you want to open. Should compile without any errors.

Comment: How would that look? I'm having trouble registering my button for events

Comment: That's what I think it should be -- did I goof?

`Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
)
         

        
        
        }
  
        
        
        
        
        
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Rebol 3, this easily:

```
REBOL [] 
load-gui 
view [button "Go" on-action [browse http://msn.com]]
```

That's a fully functioning GUI program, which runs on Android AND on desktop, using the *exact same* code across all platforms.  Take a look at:

http://rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&permalink=Nick25-Aug-2013/10:08:38-7:00&archiveflag=new

Answer (score 0):

Simple create one WebView in xml

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/web_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />
```

Here is the Simple java code for that

```
String URL="www.gtumca.co.cc";
WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.layout.web_view);

onClick()
{
    wv.loadUrl(URL);
}
```

Comment: I've added the top code to my .XML file -- where exactly does the Java code go? In my .java file or elsewhere. Thank you for the help!

Comment: you have to use java code in my.java file and

    wv.loadUrl(URL);

paste this code in

onClick()  function of Button.